# Jmeter - ISO8583 message generated invalid bitmap

Tags: jmeter, iso8583

I have configured Jmeter with ISO8583 message component and sending the message to server. The output HEX message of Bitmap is converted to an invalid format.
Below is the Console output of Jmeter:

`2021-02-25 13:49:20,217 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Running the test!
2021-02-25 13:49:20,217 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: []
2021-02-25 13:49:20,217 DEBUG n.c.b.j.i.ISO8583Config: Creating Q2
2021-02-25 13:49:20,233 INFO n.c.b.j.i.Q2: (Q2.system) Q2 started, deployDir=E:\jmeter\apache-jmeter-5.1.1\apache-jmeter-5.1.1\bin\deploy, environment=default
2021-02-25 13:49:20,233 DEBUG n.c.b.j.i.Q2: (Q2.system) [version] jPOS 2.1.4 master/6225824 (2020-03-31 18:07:15 UYT)

-----BEGIN PGP SIGNED MESSAGE-----
Hash: SHA1

jPOS Community Edition, licensed under GNU AGPL v3.0.
This software is probably not suitable for commercial use.
Please see http://jpos.org/license for details.

-----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----
Version: GnuPG v1.4.9 (Darwin)
'
iQEcBAEBAgAGBQJMolHDAAoJEOQyeO71nYtFv74H/3OgehDGEy1VXp2U3/GcAobg
HH2eZjPUz53r38ARPiU3pzm9LwDa3WZgJJaa/b9VrJwKvbPwe9+0kY3gScDE1skT
ladHt+KHHmGQArEutkzHlpZa73RbroFEIa1qmN6MaDEHGoxZqDh0Sv2cpvOaVYGO
St8ZaddLBPC17bSjAPWo9sWbvL7FgPFOHhnPmbeux8SLtnfWxXWsgo5hLBanKmO1
1z+I/w/6DL6ZYZU6bAJUk+eyVVImJqw0x3IEElI07Nh9MC6BA4iJ77ejobj8HI2r
q9ulRPEqH9NR79619lNKVUkE206dVlXo7xHmJS1QZy5v/GT66xBxyDVfTduPFXk=
=oP+v'
-----END PGP SIGNATURE-----

2021-02-25 13:49:20,248 DEBUG n.c.b.j.i.ISO8583Config: 'ISO8583 Connection Configuration' setting up QBeans jmeter-4f9f9226
2021-02-25 13:49:20,248 DEBUG n.c.b.j.i.ISO8583Config: Deploying jmeter-4f9f9226-sendjmeter-4f9f9226-receive10000yes
2021-02-25 13:49:20,264 DEBUG n.c.b.j.i.ISO8583Config: Deploying jmeter-4f9f9226-receivejmeter-4f9f9226-sendjmeter-4f9f9226-unhandledjmeter-4f9f9226.ready11
2021-02-25 13:49:20,264 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(true, *local*)
2021-02-25 13:49:20,514 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting ThreadGroup: 1 : Thread Group
2021-02-25 13:49:20,514 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting 1 threads for group Thread Group.
2021-02-25 13:49:20,514 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Thread will continue on error
2021-02-25 13:49:20,514 DEBUG n.c.b.j.i.Q2: (channel/10.51.27.122:30122) [connect] Try 0 10.51.27.122:30122
2021-02-25 13:49:20,514 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Starting thread group... number=1 threads=1 ramp-up=1 delayedStart=false
2021-02-25 13:49:20,530 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Started thread group number 1
2021-02-25 13:49:20,530 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: All thread groups have been started
2021-02-25 13:49:20,530 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-1
2021-02-25 13:49:20,530 INFO o.a.j.u.BeanShellTestElement: 144959378033
2021-02-25 13:49:20,530 DEBUG n.c.b.j.i.ISO8583Sampler: Applying config 'ISO8583 Connection Configuration'
2021-02-25 13:49:20,530 DEBUG n.c.b.j.i.ISO8583Config: Creating packager from 'E:/jmeter/ISOXML/iso87ascii.xml'
2021-02-25 13:49:20,545 DEBUG n.c.b.j.i.ISO8583Sampler: sampleStart
2021-02-25 13:49:20,545 DEBUG n.c.b.j.i.Q2: (channel/10.51.27.122:30122) [send] Out: 0200 000459 BOS43210
2021-02-25 13:50:20,546 DEBUG n.c.b.j.i.ISO8583Sampler: sampleEnd
2021-02-25 13:50:20,546 DEBUG n.c.b.j.i.ISO8583Sampler: Packed request `
'30323030f238448108e08000000000000400010031393131303730303130303935353134353730373639303030303030303030303030303130303030323235313334393230303030343539313334393230303232353438313430313930353036313131313036313434393539333738303333424f533433323130424f53393139383736353433323130424f53535054412020202020202020202020202020202020204d4f4239383736353433323130494e333536313231313938373635343332313030383730303130303234353030323030334d4f423034353031314e504349424f535350324130343930303331323330353030313731313036303031393837363534333231303035313030365032414d4f423035363030334d4f42'

2021-02-25 13:50:20,546 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: Thread Group 1-1
2021-02-25 13:50:20,546 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-1
2021-02-25 13:50:20,546 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test listeners of end of test
2021-02-25 13:50:20,546 DEBUG n.c.b.j.i.ISO8583Config: Shutting down QBeans
2021-02-25 13:50:20,546 DEBUG n.c.b.j.i.ISO8583Config: Undeploying jmeter-4f9f9226-mux
2021-02-25 13:50:20,561 DEBUG n.c.b.j.i.ISO8583Config: Undeploying jmeter-4f9f9226-channel
2021-02-25 13:50:20,561 INFO n.c.b.j.i.Q2: (Q2.system) shutting down
2021-02-25 13:50:20,577 INFO n.c.b.j.i.Q2: (Q2.system) shutdown done
2021-02-25 13:50:20,577 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false, *local*)'

Image of Jmeter ISO8583sampler [ISO8583Sampler_Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0i9lG.png)
Image of Jmeter sampler HEX message with issue highlighted [HEX message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTcnX.png)

Comment: It's much more likely someone will respond to this if you edit the post to make it more readable and add the concrete question you're seeking an answer to.

Comment: Nothing in what you posted seems incorrect. 

It's just one way of formatting and quite honestly, there so many flavors of ISO8583 that may use different encodings of fields, headers, MTI and bitmaps that I'd be cautious to say your result is incorrect. 

Can you start by saying what you were trying to achieve?